# What are best iOS apps for physical activity monitoring

Tags: heart-rate-monitor

I have an iPhone 7 and the app store is just to vast to search and try. Any specific recommendations would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

EB

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a software recommendation request. See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

1) For your iPhone, I like Lose it! and MyFitness Pal. But in addition, here are even [more.](http://www.wellness.com/blog/13280626/top-5-apps-for-getting-into-shape-this-summer/elijah-waeterling)

2) For nutrition overall, I like [Nutrino](https://www.idropnews.com/apps/top-five-rejuvenating-health-and-nutrition-apps/6308/)